# How can I make 3d sound

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, mixing, microphone-technique, film-mixing

I Try To Made something like 3D sound 
I would like to know what to do.

This Clip Is amazing

Thanks for the help

Comment: hi, welcome to SSE. This is not a question we can answer without more information. 1. what's your setup? 2.what's your goal? 3. what have you already tried? please update your question.

Comment: Hi Arnoud, I just wanna know how to make the sound to be layers with depth. I also try to use H2N recording with Mid-side and also using the sound effect laying to the cut, pan it and balance the level. It's still not working. I wonder if it's possible to make something like this clip (having more depth and layers). What's the best tools to work on? and what's the good set up in the program to help me making this sound depth? ...Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will offer a somewhat general answer since the question is somewhat general.

The real question here is how to create the perception of physical dimensions with sound. For this we must discuss how one can figure out spacial orientation from sound.

The X-plane (left and right) can be adjusted simply using your pan knob. Sweeping it side to side will cause you to think an object is moving left to right or right to left.

The Y-Plane (towards and away from you) can be controlled with a mix of level and re-verb. Think of a situation where someone is walking towards you talking at a constant level in a room with some background noise. They will get louder as they get closer to you and softer as they walk away.

Thus you can create movement by mixing these two techniques together.

The complex plane to use is the Z-Plane (up and down) this is because the human head will typically move when focusing on sound. Imagine you are watching a rocket take off, if you were to tilt your head up so that you were always looking at the rocket you would know it was lifting from the angle of your head not the sound. The sound as it lifts off would simply get quieter and quieter as if the rocket were moving away from you. There would be no way to tell if this were up or straight away from you.

Note:

If you are mixing in stereo the above applies more or less as is. However if you are mixing for 5.1 or 7.1 surround you can create lots of effects using the added speakers.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of binaural sound.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binaural_recording

You can record binaural sound using a dummy head and two microphones that simulate human ears, or you can synthesize binaural sound with digital processing. I have a plugin called H3D Binauralizer but I don't think they make that one any more.